# send post request using Retrofit2 with row json data kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, postman

am trying to send post request to payment server payex, when i try to send the request using postman it's working fine , but throw the android is not working i get retrofit2.HttpException: HTTP 400 Bad Request as i understand the problem maybe is sending the data as row json

this is my code

```
// ViewModel

val mediaType: MediaType? = "application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull()
        val body: RequestBody = RequestBody.create(
            mediaType,
            "  {\n        \"amount\": 1000,\n        \"currency\": \"MYR\",\n        \"collection_id\": \"\",\n        \"capture\": true,\n        \"customer_name\": \"Dholfaqar\",\n        \"email\": \"udalharazi@gmail.com\",\n        \"contact_number\": \"0172572068\",\n        \"address\": \"eco sky resident\",\n        \"postcode\": \"56473\",\n        \"city\": \"kuala lumpuer\",\n        \"state\": \"kuala lumpuer\",\n        \"country\": \"malaysia\",\n        \"shipping_name\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_email\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_contact_number\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_address\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_postcode\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_city\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_state\": \"\",\n        \"shipping_country\": \"\",\n        \"description\": \"testing\",\n        \"reference_number\": \"122674\",\n        \"payment_type\": \"card\",\n        \"show_payment_types\": false,\n        \"tokenize\": false,\n        \"card_on_file\": \"\",\n        \"return_url\": \"\",\n        \"callback_url\": \"\",\n        \"accept_url\": \"\",\n        \"reject_url\": \"\",\n        \"nonce\": \"\",\n        \"source\": \"androidapp\",\n        \"expiry_date\": \"2022-11-25\"\n    }\n"
        )

        Log.d("body info : ","info => "+body.toString())
        GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {

                val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(AppApis::class.java)
                retrofit.PaymentIntents("Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYWRyaWFuQG9wZW5rb20uaW8iLCJNZXJjaGFudElkIjoiMTE3MSIsIk1JRCI6IjEwMTc4MDEiLCJjdG9zIjoidHJ1ZSIsInBhcnRuZXJzIjoidHJ1ZSIsImV4cCI6MTY2OTk1NjA1OCwiaXNzIjoicGF5ZXguaW8iLCJhdWQiOiJwYXlleC5pbyJ9.SrhMtRA39OcprOeLXxyCOYk8c8r8jVAFPzrjiob0u9A",
                    "application/json","application/json",body).enqueue(
                    object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
                        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {

                            var res = response.body()?.string()
                            Log.d("response xxxxx 43","response => "+res.toString())
                            var resobj = JSONObject(res!!)


                        }

                        override fun onFailure(
                            call: Call<ResponseBody>,
                            t: Throwable
                        ) {
                        }


                    })
            }catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("outletresponse","Exception => "+ e.toString())
            }
        }
```

```
// AppApis

// @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(AppConstants.Get_Payment_Intents)
    suspend fun PaymentIntents(
        @Header("Authorization") Authorization: String,
        @Header("accept") accept: String,
        @Header("Content-Type") Content_Type: String,
        @Body bodyParameters:
        RequestBody,
    ): Call<ResponseBody>
```

for the data type for body i try many different ways but non is working , this what i try

````
val request = PaymentRequest()
        request.amount =  amount.toString()
        request.currency =  currency
        request.collection_id =  collection_id
        request.capture =  capture.toString()
        request.customer_name =  customer_name
        request.email =  email
        request.contact_number =  contact_number
        request.address =  address
        request.postcode =  postcode
        request.city =  city
        request.state =  state
        request.country =  country
        request.shipping_name =  shipping_name
        request.shipping_email =  shipping_email
        request.shipping_contact_number =  shipping_contact_number
        request.shipping_address =  shipping_address
        request.shipping_postcode =  shipping_postcode
        request.shipping_city =  shipping_city
        request.shipping_state =  shipping_state
        request.shipping_country =  shipping_country
        request.description =  description
        request.reference_number =  reference_number
        request.payment_type =  payment_type
        request.show_payment_types =  show_payment_types.toString()
        request.tokenize =  tokenize.toString()
        request.card_on_file =  card_on_file
        request.return_url =  return_url
        request.callback_url =  callback_url
        request.accept_url =  accept_url
        request.reject_url =  reject_url
        request.nonce =  nonce
        request.source =  source
        request.expiry_date =  expiry_date 
    ```

 ``` val params2: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap() ```

 val bodyParameters = JsonObject()



this is the curl in postman which is working fine 

curl --location --request POST 'https://sandbox-payexapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/PaymentIntents' \
--header 'accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAxLzA0L3htbGRzaWctbW9yZSNobWFjLXNoYTI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9uYW1lIjoiYWRyaWFuQG9wZW5rb20uaW8iLCJNZXJjaGFudElkIjoiMTE3MSIsIk1JRCI6IjEwMTc4MDEiLCJjdG9zIjoidHJ1ZSIsInBhcnRuZXJzIjoidHJ1ZSIsImV4cCI6MTY2OTk1NjA1OCwiaXNzIjoicGF5ZXguaW8iLCJhdWQiOiJwYXlleC5pbyJ9.SrhMtRA39OcprOeLXxyCOYk8c8r8jVAFPzrjiob0u9A' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Cookie: ARRAffinity=6a0fcede443e754c9c62fee8eaa769c00469246725bdb526671819e1553ae727; ARRAffinitySameSite=6a0fcede443e754c9c62fee8eaa769c00469246725bdb526671819e1553ae727' \
--data-raw '[
    {
        "amount": 1000,
        "currency": "MYR",
        "collection_id": "",
        "capture": "true",
        "customer_name": "Dholfaqar",
        "email": "udalharazi@gmail.com",
        "contact_number": "0172572068",
        "address": "eco sky resident",
        "postcode": "56473",
        "city": "kuala lumpuer",
        "state": "kuala lumpuer",
        "country": "malaysia",
        "shipping_name": "",
        "shipping_email": "",
        "shipping_contact_number": "",
        "shipping_address": "",
        "shipping_postcode": "",
        "shipping_city": "",
        "shipping_state": "",
        "shipping_country": "",
        "description": "testing",
        "reference_number": "122674",
        "payment_type": "card",
        "show_payment_types": false,
        "tokenize": false,
        "card_on_file": "",
        "return_url": "",
        "callback_url": "",
        "accept_url": "",
        "reject_url": "",
        "nonce": "",
        "source": "androidapp",
        "expiry_date": "2022-11-25"
    }
]'
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add SerializedName annotation for keys so that when we use Retrofit it generates proper json with those keys. Using SerializedName we can map our property to jason key. Remember it is better to make the properties optional so that even if server does not response with all the keys we still able to create our rich object in client side.

exmaple:

```
data class UserInfo (
@SerializedName("user_id") val userId: Int?,
@SerializedName("user_name") val userName: String?,
@SerializedName("user_email") val userEmail: String?,
@SerializedName("user_age") val userAge: String?,
@SerializedName("user_uid") val userUid: String?
)
```